# Построение маршрута через заправки на карте при условии если маршрут не сильно увеличивается

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-places-api

Добрый день!

Необходимо строить маршрут из А в Б через заправку, но только если маршрут не увеличивается больше чем на 30%. Стандартный маршрутизатор здесь, как мне кажется не подходит.
Можно ли строить маршруты таким образом и с помощью каких инструментов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готового инструмента среди бесплатных API Яндекс.Карт нет.

Вы можете запрограммировать такую логику самостоятельно, например, так:

1. вычислить `boundingBox` маршрута методом [`getBounds()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage/?from=SO#getBounds)
2. найти заправки рядом с маршрутом через [HTTP API Геопоиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=SO) (Поиска по организациям) с учетом `boundingBox`.
3. сравнить расстояние до найденных заправок и выбрать ближайшие к нитке маршрута, например, через [метод geoQuery](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geoquery-docpage/?from=SO) `getClosestTo()`.
4. добавить к маршруту ближайшую заправку как промежуточную точку и, если маршрут увеличился менее чем на 30%, считать результат финальным

Код не привожу, так как для использования API Геопоиска нужен ключ.

Comment: Спасибо за весьма подробный совет!!! Буду пробовать.

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный :)

Comment: Отметил, но пока не знаю насколько помог)) Только начал кодить