# Как определить расстояние от точки до нитки маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть маршрут и точки на карте, точек будет очень много.
Как показать только те, которые ближе всего к маршруту (на пример в пределах 5 км от маршрута)?
В примере ниже 4 точки и четвертая находиться далеко, её показывать не нужно.

```js
var myMap, ymaps;
   // Инициализировать карту
   function init() {
    var body = $('body'),
     myMap = document.getElementById("map");

    if (!myMap) return;

    myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
     center: [53.940944, 27.596874],
     zoom: 7,
     controls: []
    });

    myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {});
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
        
        var data = {
     'points': [
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="ttl">Какойто текст о месте</a>',
       "coords": [53.510657, 26.699385]
      },
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="ttl">Какойто текст о месте</a>',
       "coords": [53.447578, 26.478903]
      },
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="ttl">Какойто текст о месте</a>',
       "coords": [53.442658, 26.570570]
      },
            {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="ttl">Какойто текст о месте</a>',
       "coords": [53.664479, 26.458647]
      }
     ]
    };
        
        function createPlacemark(item) {
     var place = new ymaps.Placemark(
      item.coords,
      {
       balloonContent: item.infoPoint
      },
            {
              preset: 'islands#dotIcon',
              iconColor: '#735184'
            }
     );
     myMap.geoObjects.add(place);
    }

    data.points.forEach(function(item, index){
      createPlacemark(item);
    });
        
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
     {
      referencePoints: [[53.902496, 27.561481], [53.451143, 26.474315]],
      params: {
       results: 1,
       routingMode: 'auto'
      }
     },
     {
      routeStrokeWidth: 5,
      routeStrokeColor: '#c51216',
      routeActiveStrokeWidth: 5,
      routeActiveStrokeColor: '#c51216',

      routeActivePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor: "#c51216",

      wayPointVisible: true,
      boundsAutoApply: true
     }
    )

    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
   }
    $(document).ready(function(){
     if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init);
    });
```

```css
#map{
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Вы можете фильтровать точки по удаленности от маршрута с помощью [geoQuery](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/?from=SO#sortByDistance)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Построение маршрута через заправки на карте при условии если маршрут не сильно увеличивается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763823/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83)

Comment: то есть в polyline мне передавать свой маршрут?

Comment: да, вам нужно работать с полилинией маршрута и точками, как с обычными геообъектами

Comment: sortByDistance для данной задачи не подходит, так как он просто сортирует все точки по удалению, мне же нужно вывести только те которые находятся вблизи маршрута, то есть брать координаты всего маршрута и проверять с координатами всех имеющихся точек, если они  ближе к примеру 5км то показывать(я так понимаю)  все что в области 5 км от маршрута как показано на картинке http://prntscr.com/i7512b

Comment: Вы можете после сортировки определить расстояние до точек и оставить только те, расстояние до которых <5км. Готового метода в API, который бы из коробки решал Вашу задачу - нет

Comment: Так как определить то расстояние, господи, я не разрабатывал api и не знаю как это делается, я понимаю что нужно определять расстояние, как это делать?

Comment: всё, теперь поняла, ваш вопрос)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Точки (Placemark) вдоль маршрута](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756685/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-placemark-%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение сам, вот рабочий пример

```css
#map{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var myMap, ymaps;
   // Инициализировать карту
   function init() {
    var winWidth  = $(window).width(),
     body = $('body'),
     myMap   = document.getElementById("map");
    if (!myMap) return;
    myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
     center: [53.940944, 27.596874],
     zoom: 7,
     controls: []
    });
    
    myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {});
    
        /*произвольные точки на карте, взят с песочницы яндекс карты, можно сделать свои*/
    var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
         "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.744522, 37.616378]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 4, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.780898, 37.642889]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 5, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.793559, 37.435983]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 6, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.800584, 37.675638]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 7, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.716733, 37.589988]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 8, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.775724, 37.56084]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 9, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.822144, 37.433781]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 10, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.87417, 37.669838]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 11, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.71677, 37.482338]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 20, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.698261, 37.730838]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 21, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.6338, 37.564769]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 22, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.639996, 37.5394]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 23, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.69023, 37.405853]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 24, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.77597, 37.5129]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 25, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.775777, 37.44218]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 35, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.843363, 37.778445]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 35, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.843363, 37.778445]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
                {"type": "Feature", "id": 35, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.753215, 37.622504]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}}
    ]
};
    /*Создаем свой маршрут*/
        var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
          {
            referencePoints: [
              [55.689722, 37.413623],
              [55.882856, 37.722728]
            ],
            params: {
              results: 1,
              routingMode: 'auto'
            }
          },
          {
            // Внешний вид путевых точек.
            pinIconFillColor: '#c51216',
            pinActiveIconFillColor: '#c51216',
            routeStrokeWidth: 5,
            routeStrokeColor: '#c51216',
            routeActiveStrokeWidth: 5,
            routeActiveStrokeColor: '#c51216',
            routeActivePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor: "#c51216",
            wayPointVisible: true,
            boundsAutoApply: true
          }
        );
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

    /*Расстояние до маршрута*/
    var threshold = 2000;
    
        
        /*когда маршрут построился без ошибок*/
        multiRoute.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
          var lineGeoObjects = multiRoute.getRoutes().toArray().map(route => new ymaps.Polyline(routeToLineString(route)));

          var lines =  new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({ children: lineGeoObjects },{ visible: false });

          myMap.geoObjects.add(lines);

          $.each(data.features, function (index, element){
            var coords = element.geometry.coordinates;

            var isNearSomeRoute = lines.toArray().some(line => {var closest = line.geometry.getClosest(coords);
                 return closest.distance < threshold;
            });
            if(isNearSomeRoute){
              var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                hintContent: 'Москва!',
                balloonContent: 'Столица России'
              });
              myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            }
          });
        });

    /*Функция которая считает попадает ли точка в диапозон threshold*/
    function routeToLineString(route) {
     var points = route.getPaths().toArray()
      .map(x => x.getSegments().toArray())
    .reduce((s, x) => s.concat(x), [])
    .map(x => x.geometry.getCoordinates())
    .reduce((s, x) => s.concat(x), []);
     return { type: 'LineString', coordinates: points };
    }
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
    if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init);
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если точек очень много, то я бы посоветовала что-то такое:

1. Грубо посчитать прямоугольную область, описывающую маршрут с нужным запасом.
2. Отфильтровать точки, попадающие в эту область.
3. Для всех точек, попадающих в область, через метод [getClosest](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILineStringGeometryAccess-docpage/#getClosest) вычислить точное расстояние до линии и отсеять те, которые находятся дальше нужного.

Comment: Ну такая идея была, только как сделать прямоугольную область не знаю, так как маршрут может быть разным, как 2 точки так и 5

Comment: Ну можно собрать все точки в массив и через метод https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/util.bounds-docpage/#fromPoints получить прямоугольную границу